# Probability and Counting

Tags: probability, self-study, combinatorics

Suppose You are ordering two pizzas.A pizza can be small,medium,large or extra large,with any combination of 8 possible toppings( getting no toppings is allowed, as is getting all 8) How many possibilities are there for your two pizzas?

Answer:- My answer is $1,048,576$ possibilities

You can select any one of the four sizes in 4 ways. You can select any combination of 8 possible toppings in $(2)^8=256$ ways. For one pizza total possibilities are $4*256=1024$.So, for two pizzas, $(1024)^2=1,048,576$ possibilities.

If we treat sizes and toppings of two pizzas indistiguishable, then we can select 6 combinations of pizzas as per sizes.

These combinations are **1)Small-Medium 2)Small-Large 3)Small-Extra Large 4)Medium-Large 5)Medium-Extra Large 6)Large-Extra Large.**

Each combinations can have **255*256=65280** different toppings from the 8 types of toppings. So the total possibilities for two pizzas are **3,91,680.**

Comment: I want to know my answer is correct or not. I don't have the  correct answer for confirmation.

Comment: First, try it for S and L pizzas with or without mushrooms & with or without sausage.

Comment: This is a `[self-study]` question, so please tell us how did you tried to solve it and where are you stuck? What kind of help you need from us? I see that you edited your question to delete the attempted solution, but it would really help if you've shown what have you tried, even if it is incorrect.

Comment: @Tim, i was not confident about the previously attempted solution, so when i got correct solution after some logical thinking, i deleted the wrong solution and added correct solution.

Comment: @jsk The answer is right as it's ((2^8)*4)^2 = 2^20 = 1.048.576

Comment: Actually it depends if the pizzas are distinguishable or not.

Comment: Expanding on @gunes' point: you're distinguishing between the cases in which (1) the 1st pizza is a small one topped with ham & the 2nd a large one topped with mushrooms, & (2) the 1st pizza is a large one topped with mushrooms & the 2nd a small one topped with ham.

Comment: @Scortchi,  Yes, I am distinguishing these case of pizzas.if pizzas are indistinguishable, what would be your answer?

Comment: First divide your $1024^2$ pairs into cases where (1) the pizzas have the same size & topping & (2) cases where they differ. Then work out what proportion of case-2 pairs are indistinguishable. It could help to start off by working it out when there's a small no. types of pizza.

Answer (score -3):

So... If you only want to know whether the answer is right or wrong.... It's right! Good job!

But for the next time, consider using http://math.stackexchange.com since your question has nothing to do with statistics or probability

EDIT: As @gunes pointed out, you must divide by two if the order of the pizzas does not matter

Comment: I think you need to try to explain why you'd divide by two - you'll probably see then why you wouldn't.

Comment: Well, there are two possible ways of ordering two pizzas (A-B and B-A) which would be indistinguishable. Please note that the original poster is just asking for a check on whether his answer is right/wrong, not a full in-detail explanation of how to get the result

Comment: @David. If you roll two distinguishable dice, there are 36 possible rolls. However, if they are not distinguishable, and 1,2 is same as 2,1, then you have 21 possible rolls 1,1 2,2,..6,6 were each only counted once, so they weren't double counted. A good trick in these problems is to make the problem simple enough that you can enumerate the possibilities and check your logic.

Comment: Or, sticking with pizza, if there are just two types, A & B, then the $2^2$ distinct ordered pairs are A-A, B-B, A-B, & B_A. How many distinct *unordered* pairs are there?

Comment: @Scortchi You are ordering two pizzas. Pizza A and Pizza B. You cannot have A-A nor B-B. You either have A-B or B-A which are the same!

Comment: If you can't have two of the same type of pizza (an odd restriction, not imposed by pizzerias in my neck of the woods), then there are only $1024^2 - 1024=1\,047\,552$ possibilities when the order does matter.

Comment: @Scorchi You're getting my point wrong. Let's say I order two pizzas: one a margarita (A) and the other one with bacon (B) If I am ordering "B-B", I am ordering two bacon pizzas, which is already considered as a distinct case, not a permutation of my margarita-bacon combination

Comment: @David Do the math for the situation that scorchi described. By your logic, you would multiply 2×2=4 (squaring the possibilities for 1st and 2nd pizza) then divide by 2 to remove the duplicates leaves you with an answer of 2, which is wrong because the 3 distinct possibilities are AA, AB, and BB. You are correct that some possibilities are double counted, but wrong about how to remove the duplicates.

Comment: I see - sorry! But is it not the case then that to get the number of distinct unordered pairs, you divide only the count of distinct ordered *unalike* pairs by two and add that to the count of distinct ordered like pairs? So with just two types of pizza, A & B, there are three distinct unordered pairs: A-A, B-B, & A-B?